# Convert multi-fasta file into seperate individual fasta files in R

Tags: r, txt, fasta

I have a multi-fasta file with 1333 individual fasta files in txt fomrat

```
>header1
ACGATGCACAAGGT.....
>header2
CCAAACGCAGGGGT.....
>header3
CCAATAAGTAGCCC.....
>header4
AAAGTCGGATTTAG.....
```

continuing till >header1333

I want to split the multi-fasta into separate individual fasta files so that it fits in my `R` code for some biological analysis which was exclusively made for a single fasta file.

I want the outcome to be like file1.txt will contain

```
>header1
ACGATGCACAAGGT.....
```

file2.txt will contain

```
>header2
CCAAACGCAGGGGT.....
```

And so on. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Is this the same as your previous question? [Split multi-fasta file into separate single fasta files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410613/split-multi-fasta-file-into-separate-single-fasta-files-in-r) (my advice is to do it outside of R, e.g. with awk: `awk '{if(substr($0, 1, 1)==">"){filename=(substr($0,2)".fa")} print $0 > filename}' multi.fasta` then read in the files individually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it in data.frame then save it in folder named `fastafolder` using a `for` loop :

```r
fasta <- read.table("~/fasta", quote="\"", comment.char="")

dir.create("~/fastafolder")

for (line in 1:nrow(fasta)) {
  rows <- 2 * line - 1
  if (rows < nrow(fasta)) {
    write(fasta[rows:(rows + 1), 1] , paste0("~/fastafolder/fasta" , line))
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the files are being saved as file.txt1, file.txt2, file.txt3 and so on which is changing their original txt format, would you suggest a way that I could change the name of all the files in the new folder to maintain the original txt format and rename them to file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt...?

Comment: Try change `write` function as  `write(fasta[rows:(rows + 1), 1], paste0("~/fastafolder/fasta", line , ".txt"))`